# Additional white spaces with xelatex and fancyvrb/Verbatim

Tags: xetex

I've tested xelatex with the following code:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\setCJKmonofont{Adobe Ming Std} 
\setmonofont{Courier Std}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},numbers=left]
test中文
"test中文"
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

There are no white spaces between "test" and unicode characters "中文".
But in the pdf result, `fancyvrb` seems output additional spaces.

[image]

Any solution to remove these spaces?

Answer (score 1):

[OP's answer-in-question converted]

I've found that `\CJKsetecglue{}` works.